# Guardar dos imagenes, bitmap y uri

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap

Buenas noches, tengo una aplicación que saca fotos y las trae de galería, puedo sacar la foto y me la guarda en un URI al igual que la imagen que traigo de la galería, ahora mi pregunta es, como creo un bitmap con la misma imagen pero comprimida y ademas guardarla en otra dirección, entonces cuando las llevo al servidor las llevo por separadas , entonces llevo la imagen en full size y la imagen comprimida

Esto lo quiero realizar para lograr lo que se llama thumbnail, entonces al cargar las fotos primero cargo la primera y despues cargo la full size

```
 if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            mImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(getContext(), this);

            mUploadBtn.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        }

        if (requestCode == 2) {

            mImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(getContext(), this);

            mUploadBtn.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                mImageUri = result.getUri();

                mUploadBtn.setImageURI(mImageUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }

    }
```

aqui guardo la imagen tomada tanto de la camara como de la galeria en mi mImageUri , ahora, quiero guardar la misma imagen en un bitmap pero comprimido un 90 % , es decir que en vez de tener un mImageUri , tambien deberia tener algo que se llame por ejemplo mImageCompress

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para los Thumbnails tenes 2 estrategias:

1. Guardar ambas versiones de la imagen en storage. De esa forma lo que harías es subir la imagen original así como una versión comprimida y recortada (lo cual se haría todo al momento de subir la imagen). Con esta estrategia simplemente muestras los thumbnails en la lista y cuando se selecciona un item recien ahi descargas la imagen full size.

Esta opción es la más performante ya que solo descargas fotos full size cuando realmente son requeridas pero tienes solicitudes y espacio redundante para los thumbnails.

2. Guardar solo las imagenes tamaño completo: Con esta estrategia guardas las imágenes en alta resolución y las descargas para mostrar los thumbnails en la lista ( lo que consistiría en un imageview en el que [aplicas un algoritmo para comprimir la imagen en vivo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android)).

Esta estrategia es más simple pero significa que las fotos en alta resolución se descargarán frecuentemente, aumentando el consumo de datos significativamente.